# Data bind style for dynamic image in vue template using laravel object

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

My code for vue template is as follows:

```
<div class="collegecardimage rounded" v-bind:style="{ 'backgroundImage': 'url(' + '/storage/college_images/{{ college.cover_image}}' + ')' }"></div>
```

The `college.cover_image` contains the name of the image with which I want to get a URL to my image in this div.
I would have easily generated URL using similar code in laravel but it has been tough with vue.

Comment: you have to put the exact path of that image

Comment: any ideas on what should do to show images from an array? I have been using <div v-for="(college, index) in colleges"> to go through the array but could get url for the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lot of experiments I got this working with the following code:

```
<div class="collegecardimage rounded" v-bind:style="{ 'backgroundImage': 'url(' + '/storage/college_images/'+ college.cover_image + ')' }"></div>
```

For img tag the following code worked:

```
<img class="collegecardimage rounded " v-bind:src="'/storage/college_images/'+ college.cover_image"/>
```

Much thanks to all the answers above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an method for this which will return exact url for this.

in my **component template:**

> `<img :src="getImageSrc(value.client_image)" alt="Image">`

**method:**

```
   getImageSrc(image){
     if(image){
        return this.baseUrl + 'image_upload/testimonial/' +image;
             }
     },
```

**data:**

```
data:function(){
            return {
                 results:{},
                 parPage: 10,
                 searchValue:'',
                 id:'',
                 baseUrl: window.base_url,
             }
         },
```

and finally in my master blade file i placed the url path:

```
  <script >
        var base_url = "{{ url('/').'/' }}";
    </script>
```

so i can get the url from anywhere. hope this will help you. thanks

Comment: Thanks. I will try this and let you know. However I wanted this to work on inline style as my UI has been designed as such.

Comment: yes you can use it inline , <img :src="getImageSrc(value.client_image)" alt="Image"> getImageSrc will call the method and get the url .

Comment: can you explain how this data function works like why are these  results:{},parPage: 10,searchValue:'',id:'' needed?